# Test Class is listed under Console Code Coverage section

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, developer-console

I've noticed some unclear behaviors when writing Apex test class. Even though these are not blocking for my implementation, I'd like to know what is going on underneath.

When using class variables or methods that are not marked as `testMethod`, the test class is listed under normal apex class to be covered even it is annotated as `@isTest`.
e.g.

[image: test class listed under apex code coverage]

If I remove the `count` variable and set the second method as a `testMethod`, the class will be removed from the code coverage list.

**Q** : What is the consideration for a class to be listed under this list? Fortunately it seems it's not counting for the org code usage though as I've checked.

**P.S.** : post has been updated as two different questions and the second one is moved [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142402/inner-class-code-coverage)

Comment: I think one question per question might be better.

Comment: This is a question there was in my mind for a while to ask. Just wrote the post and didn't aware that it's required a support work. I'll close this