# Code Coverage on Inner Class/Variable Declarations

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, inner-class

When we use an inner class, fields will not be covered unless otherwise we declare them with `{get;set;}`(even though they are accessible from the test class) Also these lines are not get counted as to be covered lines. Is this the normal standard behavior?

e.g. In below sample class I'm using an inner class. There you can see that `strFirstName` has not been covered, though it has been called from the main class constructor. The field `count` has been called and covered which is declared with `{get;set;}`

[image: code coverage issue]

Comment: Why `@TestVisible public`?

Comment: Yes, no point sorry. This is just one of the sample classes I tried in different ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line containing `strFirstName` does not require coverage because you only declare the variable, but do not instantiate it. Notice how `strTitle` requires coverage, but there you perform assignment. This behavior has nothing to do with whether or not the class definition is top-level.

The other lines that are not covered in your screenshot are the class declarations themselves. Class declarations never require coverage. Notice how neither your inner class declaration nor your top level class declaration require coverage.

---

None of the lines in white count against you. Your posted coverage is `8/8`. Note from [Checking Code Coverage](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tests_coverage.htm&language=en):

> Lines of code that are covered by tests are blue. Lines of code that aren’t covered are red. Lines of code that don’t require coverage (for example, curly brackets, comments, and System.debug calls) are left white.

Comment: Oh yes I tried instantiating inner class field without `{get;set;}` and it's now caught. If we don't instantiate them is it ok to go without having code coverage on them? Confusion is these lines are counted against apex usage, so if we have considerable amount of such lines(without instantiating) will it be a blocker for the 75% coverage at deployment?

Comment: If the line is white, it does not count towards the number of lines you must cover.

Comment: This is much helpful. Debug statements, class declarations are fine but never thought that a field doesn't need the coverage. Thanks for the info and reference @AdrianLarson

Comment: @highfive If you think about it, there isn't any code to *execute* there, per se. You don't do anything at all, really.

Comment: That's what I was also thinking lol :D